# unresolved overloaded function type -- array subscript overloading in C++

Tags: c++, operators

So I have a vector class that looks a bit like this (most methods stripped out for clarity):

```
class D3Vector {
  private:
    double _values[3];
  public:
    const double& operator[](const int index) const;
    double& operator[](const int index);
};

double& D3Vector::operator[](const int index) {
  assert(index >= 0 && index < 3);
  return _values[index];
}

const double& D3Vector::operator[](const int index) const {
  assert(index >= 0 && index < 3);
  return _values[index];
}
```

And at some point in my code I call this array subscript overload as follows:

```
void func(D3Vector centre, double radius) {
  double limits[6];
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // both these lines cause the error...
    limits[i] = centre[i] - radius;
    limits[i + 3] = centre[i] + radius;
  }
  ...
}
```

but I get this error at compile time:

```
error: invalid types '<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]' for array subscript
```

Now, I have fiddled around with the signatures of the overload functions, adding and removing the reference symbols, adding and removing const, but I'm really just guessing here.

What is the sensible way to write the array subscript operator overloads for a vector class for real numbers like this which allow us to do simple things like:

```
instance[i] = 5.7;
```

and

```
new_value = instance[j] + 17.3;
```

?

**EDIT**: the full class specification, as requested:

```
class D3Vector {
  private:
    double _values[3];
  public:
    // constructors - no args inits to 0.0
    D3Vector();
    D3Vector(const double x, const double y, const double z);

    // binary + and -:
    D3Vector operator+(const D3Vector& right);
    D3Vector operator-(const D3Vector& right);

    // unary -, reverses sign of components:
    D3Vector operator-();

    // binary *, scales components.
    D3Vector operator*(const double scale);

    // the same, as self-assignment operations:
    D3Vector& operator+=(const D3Vector& right);
    D3Vector& operator-=(const D3Vector& right);
    D3Vector& operator*=(const double scale);

    // subscript operator, for member data access.
    const double& operator[](const int index) const;
    double& operator[](const int index);

    // dot product:
    double dot(D3Vector& right);

    // cross product:
    D3Vector cross(D3Vector& right);

    // shortcut to vector length:
    double mod();

    // faster way of getting length squared:
    double mod_squared();
};
```

Comment: Do you have a function called `centre`?

Comment: Your code seems fine, but the `<unresolved overloaded function type>` looks really fishy. Could you post a complete example?

Comment: full class prototype as requested :) -and- oh, you mean a function rather than a method. No, there's no bare functions called centre that the code can see.

Comment: Maybe you have a function elsewhere in your code. Does renaming centre in that method solve your issue?

Comment: no, just tried it and renaming `centre` to `cenasdftre` does nothing; same compile error.

Comment: @tehwalrus, `limits` too?

Comment: i know it *shouldn't* matter, but how about trying to replace the `const int index` in the signature of the subscript operators with just `int index`? might be a compiler issue? what is your environment?

Comment: Make a **complete** example that shows this error.  There is an error in your code, but it's code you're not showing.  Somewhere you've convinced the compiler that `limits` or `centre` is a function.

Comment: Thanks, answer posted below. `limits` was indeed a function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As commenters are pointing out, this error pops up when you try and call a function with brackets `[]` instead of parentheses `()`. This is exactly what is happening here, and wasn't obvious because I simplified the code example.

In the question, I post and example function called `func` - this was in fact a constructor of an inherited class (hence, rather than post *all* the code, I simplified.)

The base class contains all we need to know:

```
class D3Shape {
  protected:
    double l[6];
    virtual void initilise_limits() = 0;
  public:
    virtual bool contains(D3Vector point) = 0;
    vector<double> limits();
};
```

i.e. I had confused `l`, the private member variable storing the `double[6]` I was looking for, with `limits()`, a function for retrieving them in a `std::vector<double>` container. This was complicated by the fact that I was (successfully) using my real array-subscript-overloaded class on the same line, which confused me! The compiler error "column number" on the file was in fact pointing to the first character *after* the `=`, further muddying the waters.

Many thanks to everyone who commented.